# Error parsing JSON data Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm trying to sync data and after data gets synced I receive a message from the server. Now I'm suppose to display this message. But I'm getting error when parsing it. Below is my code..

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:data{
   NSLog(@"ConnectionDidReceiveData");

   NSString *strdata=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

   NSLog(@"Data as received =%@",strdata);

   if(strdata.length>2)
   {
       SBJSON *jsonparser=[[[SBJSON alloc]init]autorelease];
       NSDictionary *res= [jsonparser objectWithString:strdata];
       NSLog(@"res = %@",res);
       NSArray *syncMessage = [res objectForKey:@"synchData"];
       NSLog(@"syncMessage = %@",syncMessage);

     //  NSDictionary *dict = [syncMessage objectAtIndex:2];
     // NSLog(@"message = %@",[dict objectForKey:@"message"]);

    for (NSDictionary *result in syncMessage) {
        NSLog(@"result = %@",[result objectForKey:@"message"]); **<---- Error Occurs Here.**
       // NSString *message = [result objectForKey:@"message"];
        //NSLog(@"Message=%@",message);
    }
 }
}
```

Error :

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x93e9880
2013-11-26 10:43:07.723 M[608:11903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to  instance 0x93e9880'
```

JSON Response...

```
syncMessage = {
   code = 0;
   fromdate = "-0-";
   message = "You have exceeded your leave count";
   todate = "-0-";
}
```

Please help.

Now the same code dosent work for this JSON, what could be wrong? My res variable is coming null.

```
  {"synchData":{"message":"DCR Sync successful","code":1,"date":"2013-11-24"}}
```

Comment: show your json response

Comment: `[__NSCFString objectForKey:]` this code indicate that the response coming is the string not dictionary thats the error

Comment: @Dilip, i saw that but when i take it as normal string it tells me its a NSDictionary.

Comment: Can you display the log of `res` and `strdata` and `syncMessage`

Comment: where is the "synchData" key in your json responce

Comment: And dont format them saw as it is

Comment: 2013-11-26 10:55:32.394 M[640:11903] res = {
    synchData =     {
        code = 0;
        fromdate = "-0-";
        message = "You have exceeded your leave count";
        todate = "-0-";
    };
}
2013-11-26 10:55:32.395 M[640:11903] syncMessage = {
    code = 0;
    fromdate = "-0-";
    message = "You have exceeded your leave count";
    todate = "-0-";
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in code parsing.
This is your JSON data

```
{ 
 synchData = { 
               code = 0; 
               fromdate = "-0-"; 
               message = "You have exceeded your leave count"; 
               todate = "-0-"; 
             };
}
```

synchData is not array but its dictionary and you are setting dictionary to array so thats the problem.

So i think problem is after this code

```
NSArray *syncMessage = [res objectForKey:@"synchData"];
       NSLog(@"syncMessage = %@",syncMessage);

     //  NSDictionary *dict = [syncMessage objectAtIndex:2];
     // NSLog(@"message = %@",[dict objectForKey:@"message"]);

    for (NSDictionary *result in syncMessage) {

        NSLog(@"result = %@",[result objectForKey:@"message"]); **<---- Error Occurs Here.**
       // NSString *message = [result objectForKey:@"message"];

        //NSLog(@"Message=%@",message);

    }
 }
```

Do it like this

```
    NSDictionary *syncMessage = [res objectForKey:@"synchData"];
    NSLog(@"result = %@",[syncMessage objectForKey:@"message"]);
```

Comment: Ah great ... your method worked. What was the problem anyways?

Comment: As i told you that you are giving the dictionary object to the array. i have just changed it to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1
Please validate your JSON using http://jsonlint.com/ 
Your JSON seems to be invalid.

Step 2
print syncMessage

```
nslog(@"syncMessage:%@",syncMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is **not** an array it is a NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *returnDataDict = [res objectForKey:@"synchData"];
NSLog(@"result = %@",[returnDataDict objectForKey:@"message"]);
```

this will be enough to get the response

Comment: @Kane : How come it is a copy ? The queston has a single direct answer who ever writes the right answer will be the same..and no need for copying such a simple direct qn

Comment: Its the same answer isnt it and dilip has given it 3 minutes before your answer. just saying chill not down-voting your answer.

Comment: @Kane It was not there when i was writing this answer..and please suggest an "different way" to write this answer.